# sending emails automatically in specific tme after every signup of user in cakephp using cron

Tags: cakephp-1.3

I would like to automate the process of sending the emails to the users who signup. After every 1 month from the time user signed up we will check a condition for every user that he has fullfilled it or not , if not then an email is sent to him automatically. And after 7 day from that if still condition is not met, an email is sent to him for the disqualification. I am aware about running a cron, but how would I check that the particular user has signed up exactly one month before. I was wondering how can implement this as Im very new to the field of PHP. Please anyone help me out. If possible please provide me with an example.

Thanks Vishal

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a queue plugin.

This one is an excellent one: https://github.com/MSeven/cakephp_queue

The plugin runs on a cron which checks every x seconds to see if a new valid job exists. One of the fields that will be relevant to you is the `not_before` field.

When creating the new job using the plugin, set `not_before` to be 30 days in the future. That way, the job will exist in the table, but will be processed when the specified amount of time has elapsed.

There are also other queue plugins available. You can check out beanstalkd if you are interested in a daemon that physically runs on your server. For most, the queue plugin should be more than ample.